# Not able to dump data from excel to MySQL using Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am creating a project for importing data from csv to MySQL using Spring batch using Spring 3.0.1.
I created the configuration for Reader, Writer and Processor beans as follows along with step and job.
The Older method using JobBuilderFactory and StepBuilderFactory is deprecated in Spring Boot  3.0

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig {
    

    
    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository playerRepository;
    
    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Player> reader()
    {
        //Subclass of ItemReader class
        
        FlatFileItemReader<Player> reader=new FlatFileItemReader<Player>();
        
        
        reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("People.csv"));
        reader.setLineMapper(getLineMapper());
        reader.setLinesToSkip(1);//Skip line in case of error
        return reader;
    }

    private LineMapper<Player> getLineMapper() {
        
        DefaultLineMapper<Player> lineMapper
=new DefaultLineMapper<Player>();
        
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer=new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] {"playerID","birthYear","","","","","birthCity","","","","","","","nameFirst","nameLast","","","","","","","","retroID","bbrefID"});
        lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(new int[] {0,1,6,13,14,22,23});
        
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Player> fieldSetMapper=new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Player>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Player.class);
        
        
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
        
        return lineMapper;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public PlayerItemProcessor processor()
    {
        return new PlayerItemProcessor();
    }
    
    
    
    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Player> writer()
    {
        return player-> {
            playerRepository.saveAll(player);
        };
    }
    

    
    @Bean
    public Job importPlayerJob(JobRepository jobRepository,Step step1)
    {
                    return new JobBuilder("PLAYER-IMPORT-JOB",jobRepository).incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1).end().build();//Write .start() if there is only one step 
                                
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository,JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager) {
        
        return new StepBuilder("step1",jobRepository).<Player,Player>chunk(10,jpaTransactionManager).reader(reader()).processor(processor()).writer(writer()).build();
        
    }
    
    
    

}
```

The PlayerItemProcessor is as follows:

```
package com.aryan.batch.config;

import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;

import com.aryan.batch.modal.Player;

public class PlayerItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Player, Player> //Input and Output
{

    @Override
    public Player process(Player player) throws Exception {
        
        return player;

}
}
```

Player Model is:

```
package com.aryan.batch.modal;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;



@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Player {


    @Id
    private String playerId;
    
    int birthYear;
    
    
    String birthCity;
    
    String nameFirst;
    
    String nameLast;
    
    String retroID;
    
    String bbrefID;
}
```

PlayerRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.aryan.batch.modal.Player;

public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, String> {

}
```

The configuration in application.yml is:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/batchdemo
    username: hbstudent
    password: hbstudent
    
  batch:
    jdbc:
      initialize-schema: always  
    
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

When I run the project, the table is created successfully, but data is not inserted in the table.  There are no errors indicating any kind of problem with the code.

Comment: You need to explicity run the job, it won't automatically run the job (it did that in earlier versions, now you need to pass a parameter to specify which job launch).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Please elaborate for a better understanding.

Comment: With Spring Boot 3, you don't need `@EnableBatchProcessing`. Have you tried to remove that annotation?

Comment: It is running after removing the annotation but now getting a parsing error with        
 IncorrectTokenCountException: Incorrect number of tokens found in record: expected 24 actual 7.                      
Parsing error at line: 2 in resource=[class path resource [People2.csv]], input=[aardsda01,1981,12,27,USA,CO,Denver,2022,2,22,USA,NJ,Atlanta,David,Aardsma,David Allan,215,75,R,R,06-04-2004,23-08-2015,aardd001,aardsda01]

Comment: Glad to hear that helped! I updated the answer accordingly. The parsing error is a different problem, please ask a different question and paste the full stacktrace of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring Boot 3, you don't need `@EnableBatchProcessing`, unless you want to take complete control on how Spring Batch is configured and executed. So if you remove that annotation, your job should be executed on startup.

On another note, you are using a `PlayerRepository`, which I guess is a JPA repository. If it is the case, make sure the transaction manager used in your step is a `JpaTransactionManager`. The reason you are not seeing data being persisted is probably related to the fact that Spring Boot auto-configures a `DataSourceTransactionManager` for the `DataSource` you provided.

> //How to specify name ?

Regarding this question in the definition of the `importPlayerJob` job bean: you have already specified the name in the `JobBuilder` bean definition in `CsvToMySqlApplication` class. That said, I see no need to define the `JobBuilder` and `StepBuilder` as beans.

Comment: I changed to JpaTransactionManager by Autowiring it and using it in the .chunk() method in place of PlatformTransactionManager, but the result was the same.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question and provide a [minimal complete](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example that reproduces the issue to be able to help you in an efficient way.

Comment: I have edited the code including the suggestions.